# Set value to model class properties swift

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, mirror

I know I can get the list of class properties using `Mirror(reflecting:)` but I can only print them. But what if I want to set properties to them and return the mirrored object.
Somwhat like this -

```
    let mirroredObj = Mirror(reflecting: User())
                for (index, property) in mirroredObj.children.enumerate() {
                        property.value = <SOME_VALUE>
                    }
    return mirroredObj
```

Or maybe some totally different approach to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to modify a class during runtime, which is impossible in Swift.

You are able to add a dictionary `[String: Any]` as a property though. It can be modified during runtime.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve ultimately is [JSONModelling](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel) in  Swift. Any approach to do that?

Comment: @Mayank Baiswar  There is now with swift 4. Decodable